# Using .NET MVC HTMLHelper .For methods doesn't generate correct ID/Name when casting viewmodel field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I got a ViewModel graph with some sub-objects.

This code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JobTypeParams.ContactCatalogId, new SelectList(paramz.ContactCatalogues, "Id", "Description"), new { @class = "select2 input-default " })
```

Generates a Request.Form key/value item with the key of: **JobTypeParams.ContactCatalogId**.
That's great because that means the MVC Model Binder can correctly map the key/value item to the corresponding field in the view model.

However! This code (using casts)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => ((AdSyncJobSpecificParameters)model.JobTypeParams).ContactCatalogId, new SelectList(paramz.ContactCatalogues, "Id", "Description"), new { @class = "select2 input-default " })
```

Generates a Request.Form key/value item with key **ContactCatalogId**. It loses the **JobTypeParams** prefix somewhere.
This leads to the modelbinder being unable to bind correct key to correct viewmodel field, and hence the problem.

I do not want to hard-code the ID because of many reasons. So how do you get the HTML Helper to correctly generate they name of the Name/Id attribute ?

Comment: Because this is inside a partial view, specific to a derived class from model.JobTypeParams.

Comment: Why don't you cast it in the controller? You appear to be making this harder than it has to be.. move the cast out of the view and your problem goes away...

Comment: @SimonWhitehead The casting is only so that I can access the property "ContactCatalogId" because it only exist on a sub class, and not the super class.   *The code example i provided hid this fact* in any case the problem remain. Cast stuff and id/name combo get's their prefixes wrong, which in turn makes the modelbinder stop binding stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't get them wrong, it's not supposed to do that.  You have an incorrect expectation of how lambda's work.  You are effectively replacing the old expression, model.JobTypeParams with a single expression of type AdSyncJobSpecificParameters.

What you should be doing is using an editor template.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobTypeParams)
```

Then, create a AdSyncJobSpecificParameters.cshtml in your EditorTemplates folder and do this:

```
@model AdSyncJobSpecificParameters

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContactCatalogId, 
    new SelectList(paramz.ContactCatalogues, "Id", "Description"), 
    new { @class = "select2 input-default " })
```

You'll need to figure out a solution for the SelectList, since it doesn't seem to be part of your model.  Maybe as a ViewBag item.

You can also create one for your superclass as well in YourSuperclass.cshtml

```
@model YourSuperclass

// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Erik! This solved the issue. I guess the core issue was the incorrect assumption about how lambdas work with expressions. Using  separate editor templates for each sub class was a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @imbageek - Whenever you have special needs based on a type, an editor template is a prefect choice.